# GitKraken change highlight of changed code in diff (like on screenshot)

Tags: git, diff, gitkraken, kdiff3

[Image :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2fB1.png)

First part of screenshot is from GitKraken, second is from GitDesktop.. how to change it? I want to use highlight like on second part.

Comment: I do not think this feature is implemented ATM. However, you already posted your question in the [GitKraken Slack](https://slack.gitkraken.com/), where it has better chances to be answered by (semi)officials.

Comment: Yeah, I posted. I though at start it's maybe using some external app (selected in preferences), which can be configured. :(